# Does spree have a product configuration extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, shopping-cart, spree

Specifically, I'm looking for a configurator that has the ability to follow some rules, something along the lines of this motherboard only accepts the following processors, this chassis can handle 24 SATA/SAS disks.

I'm not certain of a better manner to ask the question and googling has not yielded any answers.  Their trial store prototype configuration is not **exactly** what I am looking for.

If not spree, is there another store front or shopping cart that has something like this out of the box or would it simply be better for me to roll my own?

Comment: This extension is specialized enough that you would probably need to write your own.  I don't know of any that exist with this functionality.  spree_related_products might be a starting point, but that will only get you part of the way there.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have my hopes too high as too have something like this exactly out of the box, but I had hoped there was something like this I can use as a starting point.